# Fluent Nhibernate Many to Many association to multiple classes

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, many-to-many, nhibernate-mapping, any

Fluent Nhibernate Many to Many association to multiple classes
We use Nhibernate and up to now we have been able use the auto mapping. But I think this is about to change.
We have a Code class that has a many to many relation with several other classes.
I’m thinking something along these lines:

```
public class Code
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CodeUsage> Usage { get; set; }
}

class CodeUsage
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Code Code { get; set; }

    // Class, [Property,] Id for "ANY" mapping to A & B
}

class A 
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CodeUsage> Codes { get; set; }
}

class B 
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CodeUsage> Codes { get; set; }
}
```

Many to Many will lead to the creation of a linking table, in the linking table their needs come  a mapping to the classes using codes. In the documentation it is referred to as a “Any” mapping.
But I have no idea how get fluent to create one.

Thoughts anyone?  or even better: a solution <);o)}{

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't map `<many-to-any>` in Fluent NHibernate - it's not supported.

I think it may be a good reason to move to [mapping-by-code](http://notherdev.blogspot.com/2012/01/mapping-by-code-onetomany-and-other.html), that supports it well.